# The created file failed to upload by application service, also cannot modified or deleted

Tags: curl, file-upload, accessibility

On C:/program files(x86)/Application_name folder,  Application does not having full access to the created files.

Application service can be able to create a file in the app's folder. The file created could not be modify/delete by the service. When the service tries to upload the file to server through curl library. It also gets failed with curl error.

What would be reason for failing to upload files that created by app service in the above mentioned folder?